# Múltiplos Ficheiros Resources em .NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resources

É possível ter 2 ficheiros de resources no visual studio com os mesmos resources name, sendo que um deles seja destinado a ambientes de testes e outro destinado a ambientes de produção?

Answer (score 1):

Exatamente com o mesmo nome não, mas você pode ter um arquivo com o mesmo prefixo, adotando um sufixo como diferenciação, como por exemplo:

- `MinhaResource.Debug.resx`
- `MinhaResource.Release.resx`

No arquivo de configuração da sua aplicação (`App.config` ou `Web.config`, dependendo da natureza da aplicação), você pode definir a parametrização de qual ambiente está sendo usado:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Ambiente" value="Release" />
  </appSettings>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Para carregar a Resource usando essa configuração, possivelmente será necessário [criar o seu próprio `ResourceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx). Como a explicação é muito extensa, não vale a pena incluí-la na resposta.